# Creating anonymous function handle dynamically in MATLAB using numeric matrices as sources

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

I'm kinda lost in a problem where I need to (dynamically) create an anonymous function handle from huge matrices and 192 variables.

I'll try to give you an (easier) example of what I have to do and what I have in mind to achieve it (but without a clue how to do it in MATLAB ):

```
syms x1 x2 x3 x4 real
X = [x1 x2 x3 x4]'
F = [1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4]
Y = [9 8]'
my_fun = (F*X + Y)' * (F*X + Y)
%solve my_fun to min for X
```

So, this is what I want to have `(my_fun)`.

The thing is, that there will be `x1` to `x192`, **`F`** will be like 10000x192 and **`Y`** like 10000x1. Using symbolic tb is very slow and since I later have to calculate the Hessian it is superdupser slow.

I now found a way to numerically calculate the Hessian (from MATLAB file exchange) but have no clue, how to calculate `my_fun` as an (anonymous) function. I simply lack the skills of MATLAB + function handles. I already tried several things.

So, I think what I need to know is how to create **`X`** dynamically with `x(1)` to `x(192)` and then calculate `my_fun = @(x) ...`

EDIT: Thanks for the edit :)
The only thing that I can think of to solve this is by using a couple of loops to create the anonymous function handle as a string and then use `str2fun`, but I feel like this isn't the easiest way to get what I need :)

Comment: Wow, it actually works! Never thought it would be that easy.
So, this means that `symbols` will actually be converted to the function handles variables?

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer, so we can close the question. By the way: As your function is quadratic in all `X(i)` you will see your hessian will be constant. Keep this in mind if your goal will be to use it more than once, as you could precompute it. (Also: Working out a formula for the hessian by hand shouldn't be too much of a hassle.)

Comment: As an answer to *`symbols` will actually be converted to the function handles variables*: NO! This all works even if you delete the first lines `syms x1 x2 x3 x4 real`, `X = [x1 x2 x3 x4]'`. There is absolutely nothing from the symbolic toolbox involved. The `@(X)` just means: *The following expression will be a function of free variable `X`*. You could also have written: `my_fun = @(M) (F*M + Y)' * (F*M + Y)`, as this will produce **exactly the same** function.

Comment: Again, thank you very, very much :)
Unfortunately I can't pre-compute the Hessian and re-use it, since a part of the data will change several times a day. Right now it is taking up to a few minutes to compute it, which is ok. Maybe there is a way to re-use the old Hessian and compute the new one with some mathematical tricks, but right now I don't have time for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Delete your first two lines containing stuff from the symbolic toolbox. You won't need any of this.

You have two options:

### Using a function-file:

These would be the contents of the file `my_fun.m`:

```
function result = my_fun(X)
   F = [1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4];
   Y = [9 8]';
   result = (F*X + Y)' * (F*X + Y);
```

You would then pass this function as an argument using `@my_fun`.

### Using an anonymous function

You could define a function handle using an anonymous function using:

```
F = [1 2 3 4; 1 2 3 4];
Y = [9 8]';
my_fun = @(X) (F*X + Y)' * (F*X + Y);
```

This will capture the current contents of your local variables `F`and `Y`. So changing `F` or `Y` afterwards won't change `my_fun`.
In contrast to the above version you will pass this using `my_fun`.